# Instalar o MahApps.Metro em um Windows Application

Tags: c#

Tem como instalar a package MahApps.Retro (http://mahapps.com) é um Windows Application? Pois no *getting started* explica somente, em WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como informado no *slogan* da página, é apenas para **WPF**!

> Mahapps.metro a UI toolkit for WPF

Então não, não é possível utilizar com Windows Forms.